# remove multilevel column pivot table python

Tags: python

I have a pivot table with a multi-index in the name of the columns like this :
[image: table]

I want to keep the same data it is correct, but I want to give one name to each column that summarizes all the indexes to have something like this:
[image: table]

Comment: Do not link images but write relevant data in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten a multi-index by converting it to a dataframe with text columns and joining them:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_frame().astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
```

The result should not be far from what you want. But as you have not given any reproducible example, I could not test against *your* data...